# How to configure nginx as a reverse proxy to server /some-path from another servers root path /

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application running on `mydomain.com` served using NGINX. I have a second application running on a different server on a subdomin like `app2.mydomain.com`. I would like to configure nginx so that all requests to `mydomain.com/app2/*` will be served from root of `app2.mydomain.com`.

So for example when the user goes to:

`mydomain.com/app2` that request is served from `app2.mydomain.com`

or a request to

`mydomain.com/app2/users` is served from `app2.mydomain.com/users`

Also the user should never see app2.mydomain.com in their browser and the url should always stay `mydomain.com/*`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you
Sina